# Laravel store dynamic value to the config file or any files

Tags: laravel

I tried lot of ways but not work. I don't need to store .env file. I need store value permanent and rewrite using api call dynamically.
The "Config::set();" function is not work because of that value temporary.

Comment: without .env, you can create Your Own Configuration in Laravel. But that will be static, not dynamic. Seems like you want to store dynamic data, so you need to save that value's on db

Comment: perhaps you would like to use the cache to store such values and then merge them into the config at run time? then you don't have to be writing to the config files ... using the database as sta has said would be a good idea ... is this more like you are trying to do something like "settings"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to overwrite a (.php) file, you need to create it first if the file not exist

first make the file e.g test.php in `project_folder/config/` and write `<?php`, save the file

next overwrite value, in this case is config aray with key

```
$array = [
  'config_key' => 'config_value',
  'next_key' => 'next_value'
];
$fp = fopen(base_path('config/test.php'), 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php return ' . var_export($array, true) . ';');
fclose($fp);
```

to get the value you just set `config('test.config_key');`

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer @Alzafan

Comment: First time it will write and work fine. If i use same function second time, it will show error. `cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)` @ALzafan

Comment: @Gowsegan check your url is valid or not